# PyQt QTreeView, once the folder expanded, I can not delete the folder

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am implementing a workspace area that showing the files in the workspace folder by using QTreeView. The workspace itself is a object which constructed by QTreeView and QFileSystemModel and QMenu(once user right clicks, a menu will show up to do copy paste and so on)

I have several QWidgets which sits in tabs, each tab also contains a workspace obj(they are not one single object, workspace obj gets created multiple times, each tab contains one).

I implemented copy paste, delete and so on. Everything works fine except one case: 
once a folder expanded and shows its content, it can not be deleted even I collapsed it. I have to relaunch the program and delete the folder without browsing it.
If the folder is ever browsed, when I tried to delete it. it keeps showing access denied info. I tried to use os.chmod to change the permission. However, it does not allow me to do so and also shows access denied.Also, not only delete it, I can not copy it and so on.

I thought the reason may be that I created multiple workspace objects and they conflict with each other and when I delete the folder, the obj does not get the access because the others are displaying the folder. However, even I constructed only one workspace obj and added to the layouts with tabs. it still shows the same behavior: once the folder is expanded, I lost the permission. However, if the folder is not expanded ever. I can delete it successfully.

Can anyone help me on this please? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your code?